# Do curved levers change the mechanical advantage?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I came across this diagram of a piston pump and I was unable to work out if the curves in the handle of this pump change the mechanical advantage of the lever mechanism.

[image]

Or could this lever be simplified to a flat lever and have the same mechanical advantage?

[image]

Or could it be like this?

[image]

Comment: Not really. The simplified lever has two straight lines: one from the plunger to the fulcrum, and another from the fulcrum to the handle

Comment: @GabrielGolfetti I added an extra image, is this what you mean?

Comment: Exactly. Then you would need to compute the forces.

Comment: The torques are computed with the distance from the fulcrum to the point of application of the force.

Comment: From a physics lever standpoint, the two alternative designs that you sketched are equivalent to the original design. The only reasons I can see for the handle lever of actual pumps to have the design that they do are maybe the curved shape design results in lower local mechanical stresses in the metal lever, or maybe the curved lever is easy to fabricate from a straight piece of iron or steel by forging. The curved lever design is also more aesthetically pleasing than the alternative designs consisting of straight sections, and it's very possible that that was a factor in its favor, too.

Comment: Why does not somebody do or get done as a student project 1) an Adams (or equivalent) kinematic simple, planar analysis. 2) FEM analysis for stresses based on the forces of analysis 1. as a function of the turning angle? Some FEM programs can do the both at the same time, can't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the lever arm is the same regardless of curvature of the arm between the pivot and the point at which force is applied.  However, if force is applied perpendicularly to the surface of the grip on the lever,  the tilt of the grip relative to the line between the point where force is applied and the pivot can make a difference:  the applied torque will greatest if the force is applied directly perpendicular to that line.

Answer (score 1):

The initial curved design of this lever is also to avoid any binding of the small arm at the top of the piston. This curved design moves the end of the lever into a position above the top pivot point of the piston and will move to the left (in this image) of the piston allowing for all the linkages to move without interfering with each other. The second added image with the single angle lever would bind and interfere with the piston during use. While that explanation can be used to calculate the mechanical advantage this design can't be used effectively when physically made.

Comment: Did you mean bending rather than binding? (and the same closer to the end of the text)

Answer (score -1):

If you think about the two alternate drawings, it is obvious that those would be inefficient because the most efficient motion for the travel of the piston is straight up and down.  The two alternate drawings would be creating force oblique to the travel of the piston, and would obviously create too much friction on the lever connected to the piston and on the piston itself, causing it to wear out much faster.  The curved lever as the top (the top of the S shape) accommodates the necessary up and down efficiency of the piston for most effect and least friction.  And the curvature in the other direction of the bottom, continues the efficiency from the upper half of the lever, accommodating the piston motion while simultaneously giving a leverage advantage to the user from the pivot point (fulcrum).  I've been fascinated by the advantage of curved levers in dispersing force ever since I got my riding mower stuck in a tight spot on a downward slope.  Since it was a downward slope on wet grass, with a very heavy mower, the option of reversing it was ruled out due to the slick grass, and the downward force of the mower's mass (kinetic force?).  Plus, my mower engine couldn't get the power to go in reverse and just avoid the situation.  I didn't have the power on my own to lift the mower over the obstacle in front, and because of the tight space, there was no way I could use ropes or chains attacked to my truck to pull it out.  Moreover, I didn't have any kind of winch to pull it out and had no stable object I could have attached the winch to in order to offset all the forces involved. It was quite a conundrum, and I was by myself, so I would have to solve it myself.  I started thinking about the machine advantage I would have by use of some kind of lever to lift the front over the primary obstacle, which would have solved the entire problem.  But getting some kind of fulcrum into that tight space made that seemingly unworkable.  So I starting thinking about curved levers and various uses in many machines in places where I had worked.  I think the basic idea is that the force is not simply linear force applied to linear movement, but rather, the force is dispersed by the curve along a broader plane of the fulcrum, in this case the ground.  I wasn't sure if I had thought it out completely, but thought that it was worth a try. As luck would have it, I already possessed a pair of metal ramps for loading wheeled objects into the bed of my truck, which had a somewhat curved shape.  In this case, there was more of an angular shape along the plane of the ramp, so it wasn't perfectly curved, but I thought it might test this principle of dispersal of force.  Sure enough, it worked like a charm. I was able to surprisingly easily leverage my heavy lawnmower and its low deck over this Gordian knot of an obstacle.  I've been thinking about curved levers ever since and trying to understand all the dispersal of mass and force principles involved, but I'm pretty sure I have seen such things in machinery, engineering, and, indeed, the lever design of the pump handle that started this discussion.

Comment: Please consider breaking your post into paragraphs to make it easier to read for others.